# Как лучше работать с изображениями из датасета для нейронной сети?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, dataset

У меня есть датасет (папка с 500 изображениями в формате jpeg). Как лучше всего будет работать с ними ? В данный момент просто открываю по штучно jpeg формат в питон коде и считываю пиксели. Но слышал, что можно их как-то загнать в csv файл и работать с ним уже, если это так, то как это реализовать?

Comment: Первый шаг в такой реализации - ознакомление с форматом csv. Далее понимание придёт само собой, скорее всего.

Comment: Смотря какая нейросеть. Если свёрточная, то лучше всё-таки в бинарном виде файлы грузить как есть из файлов.

Comment: Сеть ART2. Просто хочу хотя бы узнать в какую сторону двигаться чтобы сделать более менее по-человечески.